# Finding a maximum pairs from a given array

Tags: algorithm

I have  giving an Array `Pairs[n][n]`.
 If `Pairs[i][j]==true` this implies that block i and j can form a pair.
I have to find out the maximum pair i can form from the given array with the following condition:
A block can be paired zero or one time.
You cannot pair more than two blocks
I can't think of any approach could you suggest me the algorithm how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
        int n = 10;
        bool[,] array = new bool[n, n];

        List<Tuple<int, int>> pairs = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

        for (int row = 0; row < array.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < array.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                if (array[row, col] == true)
                {
                    pairs.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(row, col));
                }
            }
        }

        // Prints the combinations
        foreach (var pair in pairs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", pair.Item1, pair.Item2);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array represents a graph, and `Pairs[i][j]==true` denotes edge between ith and jth vertices.

So this problem is [maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_matching) for general graph, and possible approach is [Edmonds's matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds's_matching_algorithm)